# Issues installing SSL cert on single instance Tomcat though .ebextensions

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl

I am trying to follow these docs to install SSL cert to single instance tomcat: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html

The config file is getting picked up properly by EBS, but the command `killall httpd` is failing saying that there are no known **httpd** processes.
Does the standard AMI for tomcat even run Apache? What am I missing?

Here is the error:

> Application update failed at 2016-09-12T18:07:04Z with exit status 1
>   and error: container_command killhttpd in
>   .ebextensions/https-instance.config failed.+
>   +httpd: no process found.

Here is what I have as a config file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8443/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8443/
        ProxyPreserveHost on

      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

If I remove container commands completely nothing changes. HTTPS is not accessible. And I did open port 443 on the instance.